# How can I give the user the option of picking which mode to play in?

Tags: python

I want to give the user the choice of whether they want to have the coordinates randomized or whether they want to input them for a battleships game on Python. It should be noted i'm using a portable application of PyScripter to build this.

**Randomized Version**

```
from random import randint

Battleship_Board =[]


for x in range (0,5):
Battleship_Board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board):
for row in Battleship_Board:
    print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleships!")
print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)

def random_row(Battleship_Board):
return randint(0, len(Battleship_Board) - 1)

def random_col(Battleship_Board):
return randint(0, len(Battleship_Board[0]) - 1)

Battleship_Row = random_row(Battleship_Board)
Battleship_Column = random_col(Battleship_Board)

for turn in range(5):
    Guess_Board_Row = int(input("Guesss the X value"))
    Guess_Board_Column = int(input("Guess the Y value"))

if Guess_Board_Row == Battleship_Row and Guess_Board_Column == Battleship_Column:
    print("You sunk my battleship!")
    break
else:

    if (Guess_Board_Row < 1 or Guess_Board_Row > 5) or (Guess_Board_Column < 1 or Guess_Board_Column > 5):
            print("Apologies, that's not on the grid")

    elif(Battleship_Board[Guess_Board_Row][Guess_Board_Column] == "X"):
            print("You already guessed that value")

    else:
        print("You missed my battleship")
        Battleship_Board[Guess_Board_Row][Guess_Board_Column] = "X"

        print("Turn" + str(turn+1) + " out of 4.")
        print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)

    if turn >=4:
        print("Game Over")
```

As you can see I'm letting the user play the game based on a randomized value for the column and row.

**Inputted Version**

```
Battleship_Board =[]


for x in range (0,5):
Battleship_Board.append(["O"] * 5)



def print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board):
for row in Battleship_Board:
    print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleships!")
print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)

Battleship_Row =  int(input("Please enter a X value"))
Battleship_Column = int(input("Please enter a Y value"))

if (Battleship_Row < 1 or Battleship_Row > 5) or (Battleship_Column < 1 or Battleship_Row > 5):
print("Apologies, that's not on the grid")

for turn in range(5):
    Guess_Board_Row = int(input("Guess the X value"))
    Guess_Board_Column = int(input("Guess the Y value"))

if Guess_Board_Row == Battleship_Row and Guess_Board_Column == Battleship_Column:
    print("You sunk my battleship!")
    print("My Ship was here: [" + str(Battleship_Row) + "][" + str(Battleship_Column) + "]")
    break

else:
    if turn == 5:
        Battleship_Board[Battleship_Row][Battleship_Column] = "X"
        print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)
        print("Game Over")
        print("My Ship was here: [" + str(Battleship_Row) + "][" + str(Battleship_Column) + "]")

    else:
        if (Guess_Board_Row < 1 or Guess_Board_Row > 5) or (Guess_Board_Column < 1 or Guess_Board_Column > 5):
            print("Apologies, that's not on the grid")

        elif(Battleship_Board[Guess_Board_Row][Guess_Board_Column] == "X"):
            print("You already guessed that value")

        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            Battleship_Board[Guess_Board_Row][Guess_Board_Column] = "X"

        print("Turns taken out of 5:", turn + 1)
        print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)
```

Here is the one where the user gets to input the values.

I want to establish option between these two versions for the user to pick when starting up the application. How can I do that?

Comment: An `if` statement?

Comment: I assumed as much, but I wasn't sure how to layout the entirety of all the code, considering i'd need to differentiate these two versions for python to understand and run it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Made any attempts at a menu script/function/class or something similar?

Comment: I didn't know where to start, that's why i've come here. I need some professional help on where it is i should start doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use command-line arguments that allow the user to choose the mode while he fires the game up:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '<some-value>':
    # Randomize
else:
    # Prompt user for input
```

More about command-line arguments [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm). For user-friendlier (read fancier) command-line options, check out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html).